# XPath failing for namespaced XML via SQL EXTRACTVALUE?

Tags: sql, xml, xpath, soap

I have am trying to parse `FaultMessage` from an XML response using `EXTRACTVALUE`.  Below is my SQL code:

```
SELECT EXTRACTVALUE( XMLTYPE('
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <s:Fault>
      <faultcode>s:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring xml:lang="tr-TR">İstek şeması doğrulanamadı. Lütfen tüm bilgileri kontrol edin.</faultstring>
      <detail>
        <Fault xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CustomServiceLibrary.DataContract" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
          <FaultCode>Schema_Customer_005|1e8c66-c333-4357-9c7d-3f4fcd553</FaultCode>
          <FaulCategory>Schema</FaulCategory>
          <FaultMessage> Customer name can not be blank, can not contain spaces, or any special characters. LASTNAMEFIRSTNAME is the required format. </FaultMessage>
          <FaultDetailedMessage>UMUT DEMIRCI</FaultDetailedMessage>
        </Fault>
      </detail>
    </s:Fault>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>'),    
    '/s:Envelope/s:Body/s:Fault/detail/*:Fault/FaultMessage',
    'xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CustomServiceLibrary.DataContract" ') a
FROM DUAL
```

Please suggest how I can get `FaultMessage`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Given:**

1. The deeper `Fault` element ***and its descendents*** are in the `http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CustomServiceLibrary.DataContract` namespace.
2. You appear to have already defined the `a` namespace prefix for `http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CustomServiceLibrary.DataContract`
3. Using `*` as a wildcard for a namespace prefix requires XPath 2.0+.

**Change**

```
/s:Envelope/s:Body/s:Fault/detail/*:Fault/FaultMessage
```

**to**

```
/s:Envelope/s:Body/s:Fault/detail/a:Fault/a:FaultMessage
```

**so that your XPath will be correct and not require an XPath 2.0+ processor.**